# React router not returning dynamic path

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

I am using react router with these routes :

```
let routes = [{
  path : homePath,
  component : Layout,
  indexRoute: { component : Home },
  childRoutes : [
    {
      path : "translations",
      component : Translation,
    },
    {
      path : "articles",
      component : Articles,
    },{
      path : "article/:id",
      component : Article,
    },
    {
      path : "contact",
      component : Contact,
    },
  ],
}];
ReactDOM.render(
  <Router routes = {routes} history = {rRouter.browserHistory}>
  </Router>
  ,app);
```

Components :

```
class Articles extends React.Component{
  render(){
    return(
      <h1>Articles</h1>
    );
  }
}
class Article extends React.Component{
  render(){
    console.log(this.props);
    return(
      <h1>Article</h1>
    );
  }
}
```

index.html :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name=viewport content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1">
    <title>HYassin</title>
    <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Raleway' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'/>
    <link href='http://yui.yahooapis.com/pure/0.6.0/pure-min.css' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'/>
    <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.6.3/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
    <link href="http://localhost/Hyassin/src/css/main.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
    <!--  React stuff  -->
    <script src = "https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.3.1/react.js"></script>
    <script src = "https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.3.1/react-dom.min.js"></script>
    <script src = "https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-router/2.7.0/ReactRouter.js"></script>
    <script src = "https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/superagent/2.2.0/superagent.js"></script>
    <script src = "https://unpkg.com/mobx@2.5.1/lib/mobx.umd.js"></script>
    <script src='https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js'></script>
</head>

  <body>
    <div id = "webapp"></div>
    <script src = "./src/js/bundle.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

.htaccess

```
RewriteEngine On
  RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{REQUEST_URI} -f [OR]
  RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{REQUEST_URI} -d
  RewriteRule ^ - [L]
  RewriteRule ^ /index.php [L]
```

If i try to go to the path localhost/articles it works fine,however if i try to use localhost/article/1 it gives me the following error `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <`.Components and routes are in the same js file. What could be the reason for this error? Thank you for your time.

Comment: Sounds like something is expecting Javascript but receiving HTML - check your network tab

Comment: can you provide express routes, and index.html

Comment: Have you set an URL fallback on your development server ? Are you serving your `index.html` even when trying to access an unknown route on your development server ?

Comment: I already found the answer to my issue

Answer (score 0):

Turns out that the issue was caused by the way I included my script file.Instead of `src = "/src/js/bundle.js"` I had to change to `src ="http://localhost/src/js/bundle.js"`